# Worst-case time complexity of a recursive dividing function?

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity, big-o

Given this algorithm:

```
void turtle_down(double val){
    if (val >= 1.0)
        turtle_down(val/2.0);
}
```

From what I know, T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1).

O(1) is the worst-case time complexity of the base function which is val != 0.0 (am i getting this right?).
And then the recursive call gives a time complexity of T(n/2) since we divide n before the recursive call. Is that right?

But I don't understand how to do the math here. I don't know how will we arrive at O(log n)(base 2). Anyone care to explain or show me the math?

Comment: Dividing a number does not divide the complexity, either.

Comment: Depending on if your compiler is using an 80-bit floating point register or a 64-bit in-memory variable this will behave differently. For what it's worth, on my machine it takes about 1094 divisions to zero out. On yours it may be different. The input value does not seem to impact the number of cycles in any meaningful way, that 1 takes 1074 cycles and 1e99 takes 1403.

Comment: Oh wait sorry,  forgot to edit that part, it was suppose to be greater than 1

Comment: @asmmo sorry i fixed it, it was supposed  to be val >= 1

Comment: To understand a mathematical function, it often helps to know a few values. How many steps does the algorithm take if the initial input is integer values 1 up to 10? This isn't a proof, but it can get you started thinking in the right direction to what the actual answer is and why.

Comment: Hey @aschepler ! You have to update your profile. It's not Ansaldo anymore ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void turtle_down(double val){
    if (val != 0.0)
        turtle_down(val/2.0);
}
```

In the above code, the test condition  `if (val != 0.0)` may not give you the expected result. It would go into an infinite loop. Consider the case when val=32. You can see that it will never reach 0 by repeated division with 2.

But if you replace the test condition with say `if (val >= 1)` then recurrence relation for the given function will be  T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1).

In this case the time complexity is T(n) = O(log n).

To get this result you can use the Master Theorem.

To understand the given complexity consider val = 32. You can divide val repeatedly by 2, for 5 times till it becomes 1. Notice that log 32 = 5. From this we can see that the number of calls made to the function is `log n`.

Comment: I see. I've already understood that it is log n by inputing some values but i didn't know how to formally solve the big-O. I will definitely read on Master Theorem! Thank you!